# Top2Vec error - numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject

Tags: python, embedding

Error while importing top2vec:

```
import top2vec
```

My error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9f95f86c5842> in <module>
      5 from spellchecker import SpellChecker
      6 import seaborn as sns
----> 7 import top2vec

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/top2vec/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from top2vec.Top2Vec import Top2Vec
      2 
      3 __version__ = '1.0.26'

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/top2vec/Top2Vec.py in <module>
      9 from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import strip_tags
     10 import umap
---> 11 import hdbscan
     12 from wordcloud import WordCloud
     13 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hdbscan/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .hdbscan_ import HDBSCAN, hdbscan
      2 from .robust_single_linkage_ import RobustSingleLinkage, robust_single_linkage
      3 from .validity import validity_index
      4 from .prediction import (approximate_predict,
      5                          membership_vector,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py in <module>
     19 from scipy.sparse import csgraph
     20 
---> 21 from ._hdbscan_linkage import (single_linkage,
     22                                mst_linkage_core,
     23                                mst_linkage_core_vector,

hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.pyx in init hdbscan._hdbscan_linkage()

ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

I have tried to downgrade and upgrade numpy and, also, hdbscan.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74942651/9549067 See this answer, no need to upgrade Numpy